# Any plans for a Data Explorer for Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, area-51, data-explorer

As the title says...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard answer here is, yes the goal of SEDE is to be an explorer for all stack sites.

However, we need to collect more data so there is something "real" to analyze. So please be patient and remind us again in a few months if it is not there.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? It'd be great if it could be enabled!

Comment: not really, our db schemas are also a bit different which makes this even harder

Comment: @waffles: Given the planned changes to Area 51, will this ever happen? If not, would it be possible to release the db-schemas so that it would be possible to understand where the gaps are between http accessible data, and non-http accessible data.