# Tracking how close I'm to the Civic Duty badge on the main Area51 site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, area-51, badges

On the Area51 site, there's a [Civic Duty badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/32/civic-duty), which has the same requirement of 300 votes as on the other SE sites. Some people (46 as of today) have event been awarded it, so it does exist!

However, I can't seem to find out how many times I've voted to know how close I'm doing. My profile info doesn't show the voting counts, only voting on questions I've proposed. I can track Not A Good Example via the reputation tab (they show up as a red zero, I think a recent change), but the rest don't show anywhere.

As I understand it, the usual answer in the case of "How close am I to this badge" is to perform a query against the data explorer once a month. Unfortunately, Area51 isn't available on the data explorer, and I've [just been told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/any-plans-for-a-data-explorer-for-area-51/52984#52984) that this can't be changed any time soon due to schema differences.

So, in the absence of a data explorer, any chance there could be a new feature to allow a user to track their Area51 voting?

*Note - this doesn't related to the Area 51 Discussion site. While that does show vote counts, it has it's own set of badges, and the award list for the [two](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/32/civic-duty) [sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/any-plans-for-a-data-explorer-for-area-51/52984#52984) is different*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Area 51 user page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/35726?tab=stats) now shows the number of votes cast:

[image]

Comment: What about stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the badge is awarded based on your [discussion zone profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35726/gagravarr). At least, that's where the badges and the "Votes Cast" statistics are displayed.

To get to it from your Area 51 profile, click the "discussion user" link underneath your gravatar:

[image: click the "discussion user" link under your gravatar, just above the "network profile" link]

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be - there is a Civic Duty badge on both the main and discussions sites, and they have different award counts: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/badges/18/civic-duty vs http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/32/civic-duty

Comment: @Gagravarr: Oh, I see. Then the Civic Duty badge for the main site comes from voting on example questions. Either as a "great on-topic example" or a "great off-topic example".

Comment: Yup, and that's not something you can track, hence the request :)