# Which users have the most accounts with over 200 reputation across the SE networks?

Tags: discussion, reputation, rankings

Which users have the most accounts with over 200 reputation across the Stack Exchange networks?
Is it common or is it rare? I don't necessarily need a "best answer" - any answer should help (as I tend to be someone who distributes my activity across multiple networks as well).

Answer (score 7):

The "association id" or `AccountId` is now available, so I produced the requested query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168067/which-stack-exchange-users-have-the-most-accounts-with-over-200-reputation-all-ac).

Note that I [explicitly skip](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168065/generate-inner-select-for-all-users-with-rep200?opt.textResults=true) all Metas except this one, so that the query results should be the same as the number of sites with more than 200 rep that you see in a user's [accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/93791/mark-hurd?tab=accounts) tab.

Comment: Thanks, nicely done. No area51?

Comment: IIRC there's a way of doing this that does scale (instead of having to mention each site individually)

Comment: @Manishearth Because they're separate databases you need to do something that refers to them individually, but you may be able to automate the generation and then use a [dynamic query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168098/sp-executesql-available).

Comment: @MarkHurd http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/40465/user-reputation-across-all-sites

Comment: @Manishearth Updated that:  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168161/user-reputation-across-all-sites

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I include all data included in the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (except Metas for this query). See [Any plans for a Data Explorer for Area 51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52953/147650).

Answer (score 6):

While [it is possible to do cross-site queries using the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/allow-cross-site-queries-in-data-explorer/83581#83581), I don't believe it is currently possible to use the Data Explorer to [get the association id that links users across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53734/how-can-i-get-all-users-total-reputation-across-all-sites/53744#53744), so for now this would have to be done locally using a data dump, rather than online.

Answer (score 5):

A few weeks ago I created a [similar query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866924/users-with-reputation-on-many-sites-2?minimumReputation=200), which automatically scales to new Stack Exchange sites *and* provides a flexible reputation limit; it works for 200 as well for other limits. This is the current top 10:

[image]

You're ranked #345 at the moment:

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query.

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results (site nvarchar(250)
                       , accountid int
                       , displayname nvarchar(40));

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union all'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , accountid
     , displayname
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users 
where reputation >= ' + cast(##minimumReputation:int?125## as nvarchar)
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
  and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

-- execute it
exec (@sql);

with allusers as (
select
  rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as 'Rank',
  'https://stackexchange.com/users/' + cast(accountid as nvarchar)
  + '?tab=accounts|' + max(displayname) as 'User',
  count(*) AS '# of sites',
  accountid
  from #results
  group by accountid
)

-- show results
select 'Selected user' as 'Category'
     , [Rank], [User], [# of sites]
from allusers
where accountid = ##AccountId:int##
union all
select 'All users'
     , [Rank], [User], [# of sites]
from allusers
order by 1 desc, [# of sites] desc
-- AccountId: The global account ID of the user, which you can find in the URL of their network profile. Visit this link: http://stackexchange.com/users/current to see your own ID; choose if you don't want to focus on a user.

drop table #results
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.