# When will Area 51 be available on Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, area-51, data-explorer

In this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52984/200868) and [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/any-plans-for-a-data-explorer-for-area-51#comment233205_52984) made some years ago, it is mentioned that Area 51 would be added to Data Explorer in a few months. Whats the current status ?

Comment: Probably not anymore, given that they're currently working on a *replacement* for Area 51.

Comment: @animuson The replacement doesn't sound like a *replacement*, as much as an *upgrade* http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/is-a-new-area-51-site-under-development

Comment: I'm confused how you get "upgrade" from that post... But as Robert says, they're not planning to do anything more with the current Area 51 site. If they ever add it to DBSE, it will likely be the new site that replaces it, not the current one.

Comment: @ash No, it's going to be radically different, IIRC. Not an upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly? Probably never or at best not any time soon. This isn't currently on anyone's radar.

As waffles mentioned in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/any-plans-for-a-data-explorer-for-area-51#comment233205_52984), the DB schemas are different between A51 and the Q&A sites which further complicates matters. Plus, unlike with active Q&A, there's just not much benefit from having A51 in the data explorer. I'm willing to bet that just about nobody would use it.

That said, if you want to grab some A51 data for analysis, drop me an email and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thats probably a good guess. Even I am more interested in having updated site-specific data dumps being available first (for download), rather than the A51 data on SEDE (not entirely related issues, but still).

Comment: @AshRj Basically, yes. I tried to be consistent as I went through all the edit suggestions this morning. I hope I didn't miss any.

Comment: I'd like to see some statistics on why the beta sites are failing. Ok, the why is the intresting part.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Any sites in particular? It kind of tends to vary and not always come down to raw stats.